# Epplus LoadFromCollection header from class members

Tags: epplus

I am trying to create an excel file using Epplus package. I am doing this

```
static List<TestData> list = new List<TestData>
{
new TestData
{
    Name = "Mohsin",
    Number = 1
},
new TestData
{
    Name = "Ali",
    Number = 2
}
};
```

I am then calling this function

```
sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list, true);
```

I saves the correct data to the file but missing headers and I want the members of my class to be the header here. Is there a way I can achieve it without hard coding? As I would be calling it from various different types of object types?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but could not. If I use `.LoadFromCollection(list, true)` I get headers, jus as it should.

Comment: Sorry it was my bad. The header had white back ground and the text also had white color. I do have another question. Can I use attribute Display text for my properties and headers?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me like this:

```
 sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(Collection: res, PrintHeaders: true);
```

also you may like this:

```
sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list, true);
```

Probably you have some missing in your output file.